# Loop through fields of a matrix block

Tags: matrix, field

I have a matrix field shaped as follows:

- MatrixField

  - Block ( just 1 blocktype )

    - Field1
    - Field2
    - Field3
    - Field4
    - FieldN

I want to loop through all the fields inside a block, check if the field is set and other stuff. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Check if the `matrixField` is populated:

   `{% if entry.matrixField|length %}{% endif %}`
2. There are two options to pull out fields from a block type.

   **Option A:** use a for-loop pointed at your Matrix field

   ```
   // If you want to output block of a certain type
   {% if entry.matrixField|length %} 
       {% for block in entry.matrixField.type('yourBlock') %}
           {{ block.field1 }}
           {{ block.field2 }}
           {{ block.fieldN }}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}

   // OR multiple types
   {% if entry.matrixField|length %} 
       {% for block in entry.matrixField %}
           {% if block.type == "yourBlock" %}
               {{ block.field1 }}
               {{ block.field2 }}
               {{ block.fieldN }}
           {% elseif block.type == "yourBlock1" %}
               {{ block.field1 }}
               {{ block.field2 }}
               {{ block.fieldN }}
           {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   ```

   **Option B:** use simplified method of a for-loop

   ```
   {% if entry.matrixField|length %} 
       {% set yourBlock = entry.matrixField.type('yourBlock') %}
       {% for block in entry.matrixField %}
           {% switch block.type %}
               {% case "yourBlock" %}
                   {{ block.field1 }}
                   {{ block.field2 }}
                   {{ block.fieldN }}
           {% endswitch %}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   ```

Also check Craft's documentation [about Matrix Fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields#templating).